# Numbers formula for calculating *part-time* workdays per month?

Tags: macos, numbers

I want to calculate the total number of monthly workdays for part-timers.

Example, I need to calculate the full number of workdays in a month for a 3.5 day workweek, running from Tuesday to half Friday. That is, Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday are full workdays, and Friday is a half day each week. In this case, using January 2016 as an example, the answer would be 14.5 workdays.

But, I want to do this across all months, for different arrangements.

I'm struggling to get either a Count or a Networkdays function to work for this task.

Ideas for accomplishing this in a Numbers spreadsheet for Mac?

Comment: This would be a better question for StackOverflow. We don't deal with functions on AskDifferent.

Comment: Added it there. Getting downvotes! Why? @CSstudent